Can a call to an STL method be elided?
Consider the following situation:
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

class T {/*...*/};
bool predicateA(const T& t) {/*...*/}
bool predicateB(T& t) {/*...*/}

bool evaluate(std::vector<T>& vA, std::vector<T>& vB)
{
  return std::ranges::count_if(vA, predicateA) + std::ranges::count_if(vB, predicateB);
}

If std::ranges::count_if(vA, predicateA) returns a positive value, then evaluate will return true no matter what the other call to count_if returns.  Would the compiler be required to evaluate the second call to count_if anyway?  Notice that in this particular situation eliding that call might change the behavior of the program, since predicateB is allowed to have side effects.

The code is a little strange — it implicitly converts an integer to bool. If the number is not 0 or 1, you can have strange things happen (undefined behaviour). Make sure your code is correct using >0 or the double-bang idiom. You can combine two bools using bitwise & if you want to ensure that both parts get executed.

@anatolyg No, that's fine. From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Boolean_conversions regarding implicit conversions to bool: "The value zero (for integral, floating-point, and unscoped enumeration) and the null pointer and the null pointer-to-member values become false. All other values become true."

You are right. The code is fine then.

In the comment below I suggest that you probably better of using std::ranges::any_of. It has an early out mechanism and returns a Boolean which can be used with the and operator for the next early out.

No, certainly not.  The only short-circuit evaluation is that defined by the language like for && and ||.

Indeed play safe with std::ranges::count_if(...) > 0 && std::ranges::count_if(...) > 0. Since count_if itself has no early out it would even be better to use std::ranges::any_if(...) && std::ranges::any_if(...).


Would the compiler be required to evaluate the second call to count_if anyway?
Notice that in this particular situation eliding that call might change the behavior of the program, since predicateB is allowed to have side effects.

From the as-if rule, compiler cannot optimize in a way it would change behavior of the program,
except for

copy elision
removal of calls to the replaceable allocation functions (C++14)

Your code doesn't go in any of those categories so side effect of predicateB should be visible.
Notice though that operator+ doesn't enforce evaluation order of its operands, so, if predicateA doesn't do side effects (and both size cannot overflow to 0), then compiler might elide the part A when part B is positive.
